# laravel5.1 laravel in subfolder (routes not working) results in 404 apache error

Tags: apache, routes, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.1

My current setup on my production server is like the following:

there are two folders in

```
var/www/html
```

These two folders are named:

```
xyz
doge
```

Now I would like to place all requests to IP/doge into the doge folder.
This seems to work, but only the index page is working. Using the already created routes like for example:

```
ip/doge/login
```

will result in a 404 error page of apache.
Here's my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz/public
Alias "/doge" "/var/www/html/doge/public"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/xyz/public/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea where's my fault? I haven't changed the .htaccess in the public folder of each laravel project. This .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```